# In what cases or conditions jQuery.noConflict is needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symbols

I want to ask is there any practical reason where jQuery.noConflict function is needed utmost?
In layman terms I am asking, what is the reason behind the evolution of this function?

Comment: I think it came about because prototype also uses a `$` method.

Comment: Refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ for more details.

Comment: @sevenseacat Or, as I like to think of it: "the jQuery folk decided not to be complete jerks about the global namespace" xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You are using another library which also using `$`.
2. You have to use multiple versions of jQuery, mostly because the
   plugins depends on different version of jQuery.

Comment: (wrt #2, see the optional `removeAll` argument and return value)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery library and virtually all of its plugins are contained within the `jQuery` namespace. As a general rule, global objects are stored inside the jQuery namespace as well, so you shouldn't get a clash between jQuery and any other library (like prototype.js, MooTools, or YUI).

That said, there is one caveat: *by default, jQuery uses `$` as a shortcut for `jQuery`.* Thus, if you are using another JavaScript library that uses the `$` variable, you can run into conflicts with jQuery. In order to avoid these conflicts, you need to put jQuery in no-conflict mode immediately after it is loaded onto the page and before you attempt to use jQuery in your page.

for E.g

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

you can read more here http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/